# How do I append a tick icon, along the selected option in HTML select using pure CSS

Tags: html, css

I tried adding the icon by using the

```
::after
```

selector, of

```
 option:checked
```

but that didn't work, apparently, they don't have an after (maybe, I tired *::after that didn't caused any change)

```
<select>
  <option>
    abc
  </option>
  <option>
    bc
  </option>
  <option>
    c
  </option>

</select>
<style>
option:checked::after {
content:'\2713';
}
</style>
```

Comment: your code works, the `pseudo :after` is appended in your HTML (you can verify with web-developer tools). The problem is the `<select>` element doesn't know how to  display/render it. What are you expecting how this should look like?

Comment: Thanks for inspecting it. I want a tick icon next to the option name. Any idea on what do to next?

Comment: `::after` is supposed to work as if an actual child element had been inserted into the element - but `option` elements can not _have_ children, their content model is text only. (Some browsers _might_ support this, Firefox f.e. does in a similar way with `img` elements IIRC, but don’t rely on it.) Either work with a background image here to apply your “icon”, or use JavaScript to insert it into the actual text content of the selected option.

Comment: Actually yes that answers, unfortunately we can't edit it.thanks @cloned